# C# Start Applications Hidden or Minimized with StartInfo doesn't work

Tags: c#

I want to start any external application from a Windows Service. The applications should be launched hidden or minimized. The following example shows, how I have tried:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\mspaint.exe";
    //process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\calc.exe";
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    //process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.Start();
}
```

<s>For MSPaint it works, but for the calculator not. For the command `UseShellExecute` I tried `true` and `false`, but for the calculator nothing works.</s>

<s>Can anyone explain why it works for some applications like MSPaint.exe and not for other applications like Calc.exe? And is there any other way I can start the applications hidden or minimized?</s>

**EDIT:** Ok, I understand it now. I tested my program as console application, so I do not always had to reinstall the service after compiling. But because of the Session 0 Isolation I can not show a GUI Program, which is started from my service. That was a stupid idea.

Comment: "from a Windows Service" - for any modern OS (Starting from Vista), any application launched by a service shouldn't be showing any UI anywhere. In fact, usually people are trying to do the opposite (get the service to launch an application that does show up to "the" user, but that doesn't work)

Comment: You cannot see UI created by programs that you start from a service.  The service session also puts pretty strict limits on such a program, it runs with a small desktop heap.  The odds that you can get a modern UI program like Calculator going ought to be minimal.  Just don't.

Answer (score -2):

This is how i sort of got it working:

```
public const int SC_MINIMIZE = 6;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "calc.exe";
    p.Start();
    while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        p.Refresh();
    }
    ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, SC_MINIMIZE);
}
```

This will minimize the window as soon as it's fully loaded. Not too pretty but gets the job done.

Comment: Did you try `Process.WaitForInputIdle` method instead of while loop?

Comment: Did this actually work? Like you ran this code from a service and calculator opened minimized? *Where*? On your desktop? How is that even possible? The service doesn't run on your desktop!

Comment: I ran this exact code on my desktop and it opens the calculator and immediately minimizes it. Tried `Process.WaitForInputIdle` but didn't get it to work this way.